# Execute query in Symfony2 after connecting to database

Tags: oracle, symfony, doctrine

To setup my DB connection I need to send three queries (to alter Oracle's session) after opening the connection to the database.

With Propel and Symfony 1.4 it was very easy to do (in config.yml, the queries option), but Doctrine hasn't any configuration option like this.

What can I do to send these queries to Oracle? They must be ran before fetching data from the database.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this question: I've created an Event Subscriber (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) and intercepted the prePersist, preUpdate, preFlush and loadClassMetadata events.

When I catch any of these events, if I haven't sent the queries I sent them, and it's all working.